# The probability that a sum of accidentally selected distinct numbers is less than $t$

Tags: probability

Let $m,n,t\in \Bbb N$ and suppose $m\le n$. Is there a formula for calculating the probability of
$$\sum_{k=1}^ma_k\le t$$
where the distinct numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots a_m$ are chosen accidentally from the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$?

How about $t\le \sum_{k=1}^ma_k$?

Comment: Must the numbers $a_i$ be distinct?

Comment: Yes they are distinct.

Comment: I can answer your second question, at least. If we have an expression for $P(m, n, t)$, the probability that the sum is less than or equal to $t$, then the second probability is given by
$$
P\left(n-m, n, \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - t \right)
$$
since the chosen $a_i$ sums up to at least $t$ iff all the rest of the numbers sums up to at most $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - t$, which is $t$ less than the sum of all the numbers between $1$ and $n$.

Comment: @Arthur I don't know how $P\left(n-m, n, \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - t \right)$ is defined. But it answers the first question too. It seems to be $1-P\left(n-m, n, \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - t-1 \right)$?